# Request class: what is the porpouse for defining $request, $files, $query, etc, as public variables?

Tags: symfony, symfony-http-foundation

Why the variables `$request`, `$files` and `$query` are defined as `public` ? Why they were not defined `private` or `protected`?

[Check here the `Request` class](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php)

Comment: Why should they be private or protected after you ?

Comment: Why should be private/protected? All that stuff is accessible from php globals as well.